# Drools: Evaluating a list of Events using 'After'

Tags: java, list, drools

I'm really new to drools and I am trying to get a hang of some different things. Right now I need to be able to determine whether certain events happen in a certain order. The problem is that this list of events is constantly changing. Right now I have do this:

```
$a: Hit(id == A)
$b: Hit(id == B)
$c: Hit(id == C)
$d: Hit(id == D)
$e: Hit(id == E)
$f: Hit(id == F)

Hit($b after $a)
Hit($c after $b)
Hit($d after $c)
Hit($e after $d)
Hit($f after $e)
```

I would like to do something more like this:

global list events = [A, B, C, D, E, F]

For each item in this list, there exists one of each event in the session all that happen in a particular order.

F -> after -> E -> after -> D -> after -> C -> after -> B -> after -> A

Would/Could I use an accumulator for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Accumulate isn't really suitable as you cannot easily refer from one item to the one before or after.

There may be several ways of solving this - here is my proposal. Define a class `Parade`:

```
class Parade {
    List<String> chain;
    String next; 
    Hit last;
    Parade( List<String> chain ){
        this.chain = chain;
        next = chain.get(0);
        // assert chain.size() > 1
    }
    //...
}
```

Now you'll need at least three rules:

```
rule "find first Hit"
when
    $p: Parade( last == null, $next: next, $chain: chain )
    $h: Hit( id == $next )
then
    $chain.remove(0);
    modify( $p ){
        setLast( $h ),
        setNext( $chain.get(0) )
    }
end
rule "find next Hit"
when
    $p: Parade( $last: last, $next: next, $chain: chain )
    $prev: Hit( this == $last )
    $h: Hit( this after $prev, id == $next )
then
    $chain.remove(0);
    String next = $chain.size() > 0 ? $chain.get(0) : null;
    modify( $p ){
        setLast( $h ),
        setNext( next )
    }
end
```

And you'll need a third rule for detecting the complete Parade: last is not null, but next is. You might also use a list in Parade for collecting the Hits as they come.

(Note: all untried.)

Comment: This seems very useful Thank You. I haven't tried it yet, but would something like this still work if these Hit events were to expire after a certain amount of time? I have 'Hit' defined in a drl:

Comment: Why should it not work? You have registered the timely arrival of some A-B-C, so that's water under the bridge. Moreover, if you do accumulate the Hits in a list (as suggested) expiry will not destroy these objects even though they disappear from Working Memory.